# Homebrew update to PHP - Installed newer version but still showing PHP 5.4

Tags: php, homebrew

I am tying to update the PHP on my Mac OS X machine from 5.4 to 5.6.  I am using Homebrew.  I installed PHP 5.6 using Homebrew successfully: `brew install php56`.

However, when I rebooted the Unix shell, and typed the command `php -v`, it still shows PHP 5.4.10.

I ran: `export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php56)/bind:$PATH"`.

However, the `php -v` has not changed to 5.6.  What can I do to get my system to use 5.6?

Comment: Verify what PHP you are using with `which php`. Then inspect your `PATH` - `echo $PATH`. The path order of your path matters, and your system will run the first PHP executable it finds.

Comment: This covers it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed

Comment: I changed the module and restarted apache, but when running php -v I'm still getting php 5.4.  Running "which php", I get: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/php.  How do I change these path?

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX has an own php installed. The same for Python and Ruby. With Homebrew, you installed a new/extra version of php (not an update of the pre-installed version) which runs perfect separately.

The php command points to the native Mac OSX php. If you run Homebrew, the webserver will use his own php version.