# PHP5 and PHP7 - is it like Python2 and Python3? Or can I delete my PHP5-installation?

Tags: php

I'm on a Mac (OS Sierra, 10.12.6). If I run `php -v`, then it tells me, that I'm running version 5.6.30. And if I run `which php` then it gives me this path: `/usr/bin/php`.

I would like to run PHP7.1, - and I would like to install it using Homebrew. But before I do so, I thought it would be wise, to ensure that all old stuff, that can be removed - is removed.

I'm not running a local server or anything. But I still took a look inside this file: `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, - then I can see that this line is commented out:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

And I can't imagine what other programs would have PHP5 as a dependency.

I know that I can run PHP5 and PHP7 in parallel. And [the answer from this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231237/how-to-properly-and-for-once-reinstall-php-apache) stated, that as long as your `/usr/local/bin/` came before `/usr/bin` in my `$PATH$, then the Homebrew-PHP would be used. But it just seems a bit hacky, - to just 'put PHP7 in front of PHP5' and disregard any potential collision further down the line.

So to sum up... Can I delete my PHP5-installation? Or is it like with Python-versions, that there's a native version (2.7.x) that shouldn't be tinkered with, - and then you can install your own version somewhere else?

And if I can simply remove PHP5, - then how do I do it (I can't find that anywhere)? I haven't installed PHP5 myself, - and it's not installed with Brew. I have PhpStorm installed, - so it may have come with that.

Comment: You should have only one active PHP on your server

Comment: Why do you have php installed _at all_ if you are not using it? PHP is nearly exclusively used for web tasks, though other things would be possible too. Python is used as a base for many local (client side) applications, so that is a completely different story.

Comment: _"I would like to run PHP7.1"_  - For what exactly?

Comment: DainisAbols: It's not on a server. It's on my own machine. 
arkascha: I don't know why I have it installed. I think it got installed with PhpStorm or something. I haven't used it previously (locally) - I've just written it locally and uploaded all PHP-files to a server. 
MagnusEriksson: I didn't include it in the question, cause I thought it didn't matter. But I'm making a Laravel-application and developing it locally. So I would like to install Composer, Laravel, Valet, Xdebug and all that jazz... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding it as an alias, by writing `brew info php71`, finding it in the `Cellar`-folder, and then linking to it by adding this:

alias php='/usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.10_21/bin/php'

The answer was inspired by Xeoncross's answer from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46899263/1766219).

My guess is that PHP v. 5.6 came with PhpStorm. And I'm not sure if it will give problems somewhere, to change the `php`-command. If I stumble across any of that, then I'll update this post.