# Upgrade PHP 7.2 to 7.3 on Mac Mojave

Tags: php, macos-mojave

I would like to upgrade my PHP from 7.2 to 7.3 on my Mac Mojave.

My current version is 7.2.25 (when I execute `php -v`).

I did that:

```
brew install php@7.3
```

It seems that it installed some things. But `php -v` still displays 7.2.25.

I restarted my computer, and still get the same. What more can I do?

Comment: `brew unlink php@7.2 && brew link --force --overwrite php@7.3` after running this command close all terminal and open fresh terminal to see reflection.

Comment: @jagad89 would that work if the 7.2 was shipped with mojave (eg i did not follow too closely brew recently ) , or would OP also need to correct is PATH env variable to point to the appropriate directory (before the shipped php path, which was the case with my box) ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg In that case we need to update `~/.bash_profile` as per `brew` php path.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to own `/usr/local/opt`if you face any problem to unlink or link.

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/opt
```

`brew unlink php@7.2 && brew link --force --overwrite php@7.3` after running this command close all terminal and open fresh terminal to see reflection.

To change active version with Apache,in file `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`
load your desired php module. Commented php7.2 and added php7.3

```
#LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Comment: Hi jagad89. Thanks for you answer. When I try the command you mentionned, I have this error :

Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.2/7.2.25... 0 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.12...
Error: Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.

Comment: run `sudo chown -R \`whoami\`:admin /usr/local/sbin` and run above command again.

Comment: @Dom in case if you don't have `sbin` directory under `/user/local` you need to create that directory.

Comment: I created sbin. And run command again : brew unlink php@7.2 && brew link --force --overwrite php@7.3. Still thesame php version : 7.2.25

Comment: Have you closed all terminal and reopen a fresh terminal ?

Comment: yes I dit it . And just restarted the computer. Without success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203807/discussion-between-dom-and-jagad89).

Comment: Run **which php** it will return a path.

Comment: /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run either of the following commands

```
brew install php@7.3
```

**OR**

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

And The last step is

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```