# Change mac os x default php version

Tags: php, macos, php-7.1, php-7.3

In my mac (**version 10.13.6 High Sierra**) `php -v` output is `PHP 7.1.32` . 
I need to update this 7.1 version to 7.3.

i tried to remove this version using `brew unlink php7.1` but it's not worked.

How can i upgrade php version.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

$ `brew upgrade php` : ( get the latest homebrew php packages )

$ `brew install php@7.4` : ( Install php 7.4 )

$ `brew link php@7.4` : ( create an alias to this keg-only version; see comments output during installation )

$ `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile` : ( Add the alias to your path; see comments output during installation )

$ `source ~/.bash_profile` : ( Reload .bash_profile to use the new settings immediately )

**Reference** : [How to use the php that brew installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523183/how-to-use-the-php-that-brew-installed)

Comment: source ~/.bash_profile works for me, but it keeps on reverting to older version everytime I close the terminal, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: confirm if your default shell is bash. `echo $SHELL`

Answer (score 10):

First:

```
~ brew update
```

then install the latest php version (PHP 8.0.8 in the time of writing):

```
~ brew install php
```

link new version to /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.8:

```
~ brew link php
```

then open the shell's resource file, located in ~/ (in my case Z-shell or ZSH):

```
~ sudo vi .zshrc
```

press i to insert and somewhere in your resource file append a new path to your $PATH variable, like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/bin
```

or in the case of ZSH, you should also be able to do it like this:

```
path+=('/usr/local/opt/php@8.0/bin')
export PATH
```

then press esc to escape from insert mode, and press :wq to save/write and quit the editor. The final step is to source the file to apply new changes permanently.

```
~ source .zshrc
```

Try new PHP version:

```
~ php -v
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the 10.13.6 High Sierra version, but this worked for me.

1. `php -v` (To see what version php has. But you have already done that)
2. `brew unlink php55` (In my case I use php 5.5)
3. `brew install php73` (For the php 7.3 version.)
4. `php -v` (To check of the version is the one I need.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem maintaining homebrew for both of the arch (arm64 and x86_64).
In that case I choose Homebrew location dynamically depending on the terminal arch in my `.bashrc`.

```sh
if [[ $(uname -m) == "x86_64" ]]; then
  echo "x86_64 detected" 
  export PATH=/usr/local/Homebrew/bin:$PATH
else
  echo "arm64 detected"
  export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
fi
```

And installed `tmux` in both of the terminal (native and rosetta) and after reload it works correctly. Full `.zshrc` [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/RafikFarhad/1fba93656a798a00dcfda4b2586d9dcd).